# Session tracking in HttpSession or in Stateful Session Bean?

Tags: jsf, session, httpsession, stateful-session-bean

I want to develop a jsf web application like shopping cart and must have to login before shopping. How can i tracking each user session. What will be the best way in this situation. Track session in presentation layer (HttpSession) or Stateful Session Bean in server side.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Generally when using EJB Statefull session bean there is thought of to try having somekind of state management needed between same client calls and client is not http/https based. Ideally these should not be used client should manage its own state not service.

User sessions are better kept in war using http session management not in ear/ejbs.